# Laravel where clause timediff

Tags: laravel

I have a working query in place, but I want to add a clause to only show records that have a 'tbldomains.nextduedate' further then 30 days away.

```
Capsule::table('tblhosting')
    ->select('*','tbldomains.nextduedate as domainnextduedate' , 'tblhosting.nextduedate as hostingnextduedate','tbldomains.id as domainid' , 'tblhosting.id as hostingid')
        ->join('tblclients', 'tblhosting.userid', '=', 'tblclients.id')
        ->join('tbldomains', 'tblhosting.domain', '=', 'tbldomains.domain')         
        ->whereColumn('tblhosting.nextduedate', '!=', 'tbldomains.nextduedate')
        ->where('tbldomains.status', '=', 'Active')
        ->whereDate('tblhosting.termination_date', '=', '0000-00-00')
        ->where('tblhosting.nextduedate', '!=', '0000-00-00')   
        ->where('tblhosting.server', '!=', '0')             
        ->get()
```

What I tried:

```
->where(Capsule::raw('DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),tbldomains.nextduedate)'),'>','30')
```

but that does not seem tow work in Laravel

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [`Carbon`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) quite easily (which comes with Laravel).

Carbon has an [`addDays()`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub) function, so we can use that like this to add 30 days from the current day:

```
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays(30);
```

You can use it on your `where` clause like this:

```
->where('tbldomains.nextduedate', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays(30))
```